# Check if a type is a partial order

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, spaceship-operator

Can a type be checked for partial ordering property in C++20? If so, how can such a check be made with the use of concepts?

Is the the following code enough for this purpose?

```
#include <compare>
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
concept PartialOrder = requires (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
  // Is there any caveat in this?
  { lhs <=> rhs } -> std::convertible_to<std::partial_ordering>;
};
```

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of "partial ordering property" in mind?

Comment: As far as C++20 [current definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/partial_ordering) of partial ordering is concerned yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There already is such a concept in the [standard library](https://eel.is/c++draft/cmp.concept): `three_way_comparable`. `T` satisfies `three_way_comparable` if *all* the binary comparison operators and `<=>` are all valid expressions and the invocation of `<=>` gives you at least `std::partial_ordering`.

It's a little bit more involved than the one you're proposing - partially to avoid weird types (e.g. maybe some type defines `operator<=>` but also deletes `operator<=` for whatever reason? Let's just exclude those...) but also because having an ordering require equality is also pretty sensible. Just because a type is only partially ordered doesn't need it can't support `==` as well.

One other point is your `PartialOrder<T&>` actually ends up comparing *non-const* objects of type `T`, rather than `const` ones. Which isn't ideal. That's why the standard does this `const remove_reference_t<T>&` dance.

Note that neither what you're suggesting nor the standard library concept checks that a type is *only* partially ordered, just that it's *at least* partially ordered. `int` satisfies both `std::three_way_comparable` and your `PartialOrder` concepts, despite obviously having a total order.

---

One way of achieving proper subsumption with this particular concept is:

```
template <typename T>
concept partially_ordered = std::three_way_comparable<T>;

template <typename T>
concept totally_ordered = partially_ordered<T> &&
    requires (std::remove_cvref_t<T> const& lhs, std::remove_cvref_t<T> const& rhs) {
        { lhs <=> rhs } -> std::convertible_to<std::weak_ordering>;
    };
```

Or to be lazier:

```
template <typename T>
concept totally_ordered = partially_ordered<T> &&
    std::three_way_comparable<T, std::weak_ordering>;
```

Possibly by replacing `weak_ordering` with `strong_ordering`.

Also note that there is a `std::totally_ordered` concept - but it does not require `<=>`.

Comment: I am assuming that total order subsumes partial order, hence why the check for convertibility instead of sameness

Comment: C++ is not alone in putting ordering and equivalency in the same page: [1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html). Semantically speaking, it seems like a sensible choice.